# IOS - method stops executing after for loop

Tags: ios, xcode

In a view controller I am calling this method:

```
- (void)method{

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AllFiles"];
[query whereKey:@"userID" equalTo:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"KeyMyUserID"]];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

    if (!error) {

        NSMutableArray *localIds = [DBManager getAllFileIdsForUserID:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"KeyMyUserID"]];
        NSMutableArray *onlineIds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

       NSLog(@"log1");

        for (PFObject *object in objects)
            [onlineIds addObject:object[@"assignedObjectId"]];

        NSLog(@"log2");

        for (PFObject *object in objects)
            if ([DBManager objectWasDeletedLocallyWithId:object[@"assignedObjectId"]]){

                [self deleteFileForUserID:object[@"userID"] withObjectId:object[@"assignedObjectId"] completition:nil];

            }else if (![localIds containsObject:object[@"assignedObjectId"]] && ![DBManager objectWasDeletedLocallyWithId:object[@"assignedObjectId"]]){

                [self downloadFileWithObjectId:object[@"assignedObjectId"] forUserID:object[@"userID"]];

            }

        for (NSString* objectId in localIds)
            if (![onlineIds containsObject:objectId])
                [self uploadFileWithObjectId:objectId];

    }else{
        // Log details of the failure
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

 NSLog(@"log3");

}];
}
```

A VERY weird thing happens, that I have never seen before. It seems that the method execution is stopped after the initial for loop.

Like this, log1 is outputted, but the other two logs no. If I remove

```
for (PFObject *object in objects)
            [onlineIds addObject:object[@"assignedObjectId"]];
```

then magically the log1 and log2 are outputted, but not log 3.
It still doesn't work if I do:

```
for (PFObject *object in objects){
            [onlineIds addObject:object[@"assignedObjectId"]];
}
```

This makes no sense. I use this same exact code in other parts and it works. It seems as if there was a bug in the for loop. Has anybody seen this before?

Comment: Did you check if `object[@"assignedObjectId"] == nil`?

Comment: No, but even if it was nil, why would it block the whole method?

Comment: you'r right, thats the problem. However I still don't understand, it has never happened before...

Comment: You can't add a `nil` into an array. It should throw an exception in this line `[onlineIds addObject:object[@"assignedObjectId"]];`

Comment: Then why doesn't it throw an exception?

Comment: You must enable All Exceptions breakpoint. Look at breakpoint tab, if you don't see `All Exceptions` then press Plus icon at the bottom right corner and add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is probably a listener reacting to that addObject: method. The execution of that listener might be crashing.

I had a similar problem when using addOverlay: on a MKMapView that was triggering a call to mapView:rendererForOverlay: and that call was crashing.

Carlos.